# Error-Logging Decorator with separate/isolated exception handling inside a function

Tags: python, exception, logging, decorator

Is there a way to write a generic logging-decorator, which logs all exceptions occurring inside a function or method (both the handled and unhandled exceptions), but doesn't affect the exception handling inside the function itself ? This could be useful to log the exceptions within a generic decorator, but to keep the function-specific exception handling part.